# How to map a list using sublist as key and parent object as value

Tags: java, java-stream

```java
public class User {
    private String userId;
    private String role;
    private List<String> privileges;
}
```

Given a `List<User> users` how do I get a `Map<String, List<User>>` where the key is each privilege from the user?

This code generates a Map<List, List> instead of the intended single string key

```java
users.stream().collect(Collectors
.groupingBy(User::getPrivileges, HashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(v -> v, Collectors.toList())));
```

And if I do a flatmap, there's no way to reference the parent object

```java
users.stream()
.flatMap(User::getPrivileges)
.collect(Collectors
.groupingBy(v->v, HashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(???, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "key is **each** privilege from the user"? A key for a `Map` has to be a single object (`List` **is** a single object).

Comment: e.g. if users[0].privileges[] = "p1", "p2" and users[1].privileges[] = "p3", the map should have 3 entries with keys "p1", "p2", "p3" and values of user0, user0, and user1 respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a temporary pair that holds both the privilege (after flattening the list) and the related user, which you can then use in a grouping collector:

```
Map<String, List<User>> result = users.stream()
        .flatMap(user -> user.getPrivileges()
                .stream()
                .map(priv -> new SimpleEntry<>(priv, user)))
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, 
                    Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```