# java8 - stream API for inner list of same type of object

Tags: collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

wanted to use Java 8 stream API for the below code::

```
private Map<String,String> fetchAllSerialNumbers(IProductOrderDTO inputProductOrderDTO)
        {
            Map<String,String> serialNumbersFromToBeValidate = new HashMap<>();
            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(inputProductOrderDTO.getProductOrderItem()))
            {
                List<IProductOrderItemDTO> productOrderItems = inputProductOrderDTO.getProductOrderItem();
                for (IProductOrderItemDTO productorder : productOrderItems)
                {
                    for (IProductOrderItemDTO orderItem : productorder.getProductOrderItem()) {
    
                        List<ICharacteristicDTO> characteristicList = orderItem.getProduct().getProductCharacteristic();
                        for(ICharacteristicDTO characteristic : characteristicList)
                        {
                            if("SIM".equals(characteristic.getName()))
                            {
                                serialNumbersFromToBeValidate.put(characteristic.getValue(),orderItem.getId());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return serialNumbersFromToBeValidate;
        }
```

Code I have tried but have not been able to complete::

```
private Map<String,String> fetchAllSerialNumbers(IProductOrderDTO inputProductOrderDTO)
{
    Map<String,String> serialNumbersFromToBeValidate = inputProductOrderDTO.getProductOrderItem().stream().
            flatMap(orderItem ->orderItem.getProductOrderItem().stream()).
            flatMap(ch -> ch.getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().stream()).
            filter(f->f.getName().equals("SIM")).
            map(ch->ch.getValue()).
            collect(Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, Function.identity()));
    // not able to get the key and value.
    // need key from map function i.e. map(ch->ch.getValue())
    // need ID as a value from this orderItem flatMap(orderItem ->orderItem.getProductOrderItem().stream()).
    
    return serialNumbersFromToBeValidate;
}
```

Model Class::

```
public interface IProductOrderItemDTO extends Serializable
{
    public List<IProductOrderItemDTO> getProductOrderItem();
    public void setProductOrderItem(List<IProductOrderItemDTO> productOrderItem);
    public IProductRefOrValueDTO getProduct();
    public void setProduct(IProductRefOrValueDTO product);
}
public interface IProductRefOrValueDTO extends Serializable
{
    public List<ICharacteristicDTO> getProductCharacteristic();
    public void setProductCharacteristic(List<ICharacteristicDTO> productCharacteristic);
}
```

Comment: Added new code and problem line. I am not able to retrieve the value and key from stream for hashmap.  key = characteristic.value and value = OrderItem ID of the inner list element.

Comment: This is similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65950180/2711488) and has a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` class to collect the filtered values, that makes to convert the stream to map later. Working code should look like something like this:

```
private Map<String,String> fetchAllSerialNumbers(IProductOrderDTO inputProductOrderDTO)   {
    return inputProductOrderDTO.getProductOrderItem().stream()
            .flatMap(productOrderItems -> productOrderItems.getProductOrderItem().stream())
            .flatMap(orderItem -> orderItem.getProduct().getProductCharacteristic()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(characteristic -> "SIM".equals(characteristic.getName()))
                    .map(characteristic -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(characteristic.getValue(), orderItem.getId())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
}
```